# Send subscribe email as email body not as text in php

Tags: php

[image: Here is image]I want to send the email to the email subscriber , here is my approach

```
$msg= file_get_contents("activate-mailer.html");
$from = $_POST['sunscribeemail']; // this is the sender's Email address
$subject = "Email Subscription for the news letter ";
$message = from . " " . Subscribe for the news letter:" . "\n\n" ;
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: " . $from;
$headers[] = "Reply-To: " . $from;
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
mail($to,$subject,$msg,implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Email sent to subscriber successfully but it is sending html as text like `<html>..</html>` but i want to render this html to the email body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the Content-Type from text to html

```
$headers[] = "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";
```

Comment: it worked for me but my logo url is changed `<img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/63CxT3p0egISL-MvLOBg7DDiUJ0AaWnwQBavWNBiPLrrSiYXq-MGQ2aPbuVwRjIT13xm5hy2SoFlBslmDQ=s0-d-e1-ft#http:///images/mailimg/linkedin-button.png" style="opacity:0.7" class="CToWUd">` how do handle this

Comment: That's GMAIL that changes the images path routing them via a proxy for security reasons. Nothing you can do :)